# Need Regular Expression for Finite Automata: Even number of 1s and Even number of 0s

Tags: regular-language, finite-automata, computation-theory, dfa

My problem may sounds different to you.

I am a beginner and I am learning Finite Automata. I am googing over Internet to find the
  Regular Expression for Finite Automata of Given Machine Below.

> [image]

Can anyone help me to  write  "Regular Expression for Finite Automata" of above machine

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: try with Arden's Therm. This answer may help you: [How to write regular expression for a DFA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7550711/what-is-the-language-of-this-deterministic-finite-automata/13965717#13965717)

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan. thanks for the link. as i am newbie, its hard to understand. :(

Comment: I written elaborately for newbie only :) Try with  Arden's Therm. Actually writing RE *directly* for your DFA bit typical. (Even with Arden's therm solution will be long)

Comment: thanks for your valuable support. I have try a lot earlier and i have seen your post only. but since i was unable to solve that , tht why i posted here. still waiting for a solution :(

Answer (score 30, accepted):

### How to write regular expression for a DFA using Arden theorem

Lets instead of language symbols `0`,`1` we take `Σ = {a, b}` and following is new DFA.

> [image: DFA]
>   Notice start state is Q<sub>0</sub>

You have not given but In my answer initial state is Q<sub>0</sub>, Where final state is also Q<sub>0</sub>.

Language accepted by is DFA is set of all strings consist of symbol *`a`* and *`b`* where number of symbol *`a`* and *`b`* are even (including `Λ`).

Some example strings are `{Λ, aa, bb, abba, babbab }`, there is no constraint of order and patter of appearance of symbol just both should be even number of time.
note: `Λ` is allowed because numberOf(`a`)  and numberOf(`b`)  is zero that is even.

As I said in my lined answer: [How to write regular expression for a DFA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7550711/what-is-the-language-of-this-deterministic-finite-automata?lq=1) every state stores some information. Below is a what information is stored in each state in above DFA.

> Q<sub>0</sub>: Even number of *`a`* and even number of *`b`*
>   Q<sub>1</sub>: Odd number of  *`a`* and even number of *`b`*
>   Q<sub>2</sub>: Odd number of  *`a`* and odd number of *`b`*
>   Q<sub>3</sub>: Even number of  *`a`* and odd number of *`b`*

(*You can make DFAs for more interesting languages by changing set of final sates*)
<sub>One should read the lined answer, because my approach to fined RE for DFA in both answer is different</sub>

**What is a Regular Expression?**
The approach is explained below using [Arden's Theorem](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/electrical-engineering/computer-engineering/9788131760772/4dot-regular-expression/navpoint55), applicable on a transition diagram in which there is a single start state and no null move defined (our DFA is in this form). The technique is explained in a book: [Formal Languages And Automata Theory](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=fodwUrSC8e0C&pg=SA3-PA7&lpg=SA3-PA7&dq=arden%27s%20theorem%20for%20regular%20language&source=bl&ots=QTuxWbiATB&sig=Rf32daVHvstUV5JyExianv6A4Pw&hl=en&sa=X&ei=sSkZUb-9E8iUrgejlIEw&ved=0CCsQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=arden%27s%20theorem%20for%20regular%20language&f=false)

Remember [4.2 ARDEN THEOREM](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/electrical-engineering/computer-engineering/9788131760772/4dot-regular-expression/navpoint55):

> Let `B` and `C` be are two Regular Expressions over `Σ`. If `C` does not contain `Λ`, then for the equation A = B + AC has a unique (one and only one) solution A = BC*.

**[Solution]:**

**Step-1**: Write initial equation, one equation for corresponding to each state in DFA. This equation means how a state can be reach in a single step

So according to our DFA following 4-equations are possible:

> 1. Q<sub>0</sub> = `Λ` + Q<sub>1</sub>a  + Q<sub>3</sub>b
> 2. Q<sub>1</sub> =  Q<sub>0</sub>a  + Q<sub>2</sub>b
> 3. Q<sub>2</sub> =  Q<sub>1</sub>b  + Q<sub>3</sub>a
> 4. Q<sub>3</sub> =  Q<sub>0</sub>b  + Q<sub>2</sub>a

In equation (1) extra `Λ` is because Q<sub>0</sub> is initial state, can be reached without any input (a point of start).
Because Q<sub>0</sub> is also only a final state, a string consist of *`a, b`* is acceptable if it ends at Q<sub>0</sub>. Value of Q<sub>0</sub> will give us required regular expression so our target is to simply equation-(1) in terms of *`a, b`*.

**Step-2:** Simplify equation using by putting value of states from other equations and using Arden's simplification equation.

Lets we first take equation-(4) and replace value of Q<sub>2</sub> from equation-(3).

> Q<sub>3</sub> =  Q<sub>0</sub>b  + Q<sub>2</sub>a
>     Q<sub>3</sub> =  Q<sub>0</sub>b  + (Q<sub>1</sub>b  + Q<sub>3</sub>a) a
>     Q<sub>3</sub> =  Q<sub>0</sub>b  + Q<sub>1</sub>ba  + Q<sub>3</sub>aa

The last equation can be view in the form of Arden's equation `A = B + AC`. Where A is Q<sub>3</sub>, B = Q<sub>0</sub>b  + Q<sub>1</sub>ba  and C = `aa`. So according to Arden's therm, equation Q<sub>3</sub> =  Q<sub>0</sub>b  + Q<sub>1</sub>ba  + Q<sub>3</sub>aa has a unique solution that is:

> Q<sub>3</sub> =  (Q<sub>0</sub>b  + Q<sub>1</sub>ba)(aa)*

Or one can write this as follows:

> `5.`   Q<sub>3</sub> =  Q<sub>0</sub>b(aa)* + Q<sub>1</sub>ba(aa)*

Logically you can check/understand eq-(5) means Q<sub>3</sub> can be reached in two ways (`+`) fist from by applying `b` on Q<sub>0</sub> then there is a loop with label `aa` on Q<sub>3</sub>, second way is from Q<sub>1</sub> with application of `ba`.

In similar ways, we can simplify equation-(2)

> Q<sub>1</sub> =  Q<sub>0</sub>a  + Q<sub>2</sub>b
>     Q<sub>1</sub> =  Q<sub>0</sub>a  + (Q<sub>1</sub>b  + Q<sub>3</sub>a)b
>     Q<sub>1</sub> =  Q<sub>0</sub>a  + Q<sub>1</sub>bb  + Q<sub>3</sub>ab

Use Arden's simplification rules here.

> Q<sub>1</sub> =  (Q<sub>0</sub>a + Q<sub>3</sub>ab)(bb)*

further simplify

> `6.`   Q<sub>1</sub> =  Q<sub>0</sub>a(bb)* + Q<sub>3</sub>ab(bb)*

Now value of Q<sub>3</sub> from equation-(5) into equation-(6)

> Q<sub>1</sub> =  Q<sub>0</sub>a(bb)* + (Q<sub>0</sub>b(aa)* + Q<sub>1</sub>ba(aa)* )ab(bb)*
>     Q<sub>1</sub> =  Q<sub>0</sub>a(bb)* + Q<sub>0</sub>b(aa)* ab(bb)*  + Q<sub>1</sub>ba(aa)* ab(bb)*

Again improve this last equation using Arden law of simplification.

> Q<sub>1</sub> =  (Q<sub>0</sub>a(bb)* + Q<sub>0</sub>b(aa)* ab(bb)* ) (ba(aa)* ab(bb)* )*

take Q<sub>0</sub> conman:

> `7.`   Q<sub>1</sub> =  Q<sub>0</sub>(a(bb)* +  b(aa)* ab(bb)* ) (ba(aa)* ab(bb)* )*

Can you understand this equation, Its how you can go to Q<sub>1</sub> from state Q<sub>0</sub>? We remember this solution as equation-(7)

As above we can evaluate value of Q<sub>1</sub> in terms of state Q<sub>0</sub> and *`a, b`*, Similarly we are to evaluate value for state Q<sub>3</sub>. For this we can simple put value of state Q<sub>1</sub>  from equation-(5) into equation-(7).

> `5.`   Q<sub>3</sub> =  Q<sub>0</sub>b(aa)* + Q<sub>1</sub>ba(aa)*
>     `.`   Q<sub>3</sub> =  Q<sub>0</sub>b(aa)* + Q<sub>0</sub>(a(bb)* +  b(aa)* ab(bb)* ) (ba(aa)* ab(bb)* )* ba(aa)*
>     `8.`   Q<sub>3</sub> =  Q<sub>0</sub> ( b(aa)* + (a(bb)* +  b(aa)* ab(bb)* ) (ba(aa)* ab(bb)* )* ba(aa)* )

Now, in equation number (1)  put value of state Q<sub>3</sub> and Q<sub>1</sub> from equation number (8)  and (7) receptively.

> Q<sub>0</sub> = `Λ` + Q<sub>1</sub>a  + Q<sub>3</sub>b
>     Q<sub>0</sub> = `Λ` + Q<sub>0</sub>(a(bb)* +  (aa)* ab(bb)* ) (ba(aa)* ab(bb)* )* a  + Q<sub>0</sub> ( b(aa)* + (a(bb)* +  b(aa)* ab(bb)* ) (ba(aa)* ab(bb)* )* ba(aa)* ) b

Now, Last time apply Arden solution to find value of state Q<sub>0</sub> in terms of symbols `a` and `b`.

> Q<sub>0</sub> = `Λ` + ( (a(bb)* +  (aa)* ab(bb)* ) (ba(aa)* ab(bb)* )* a  +  ( b(aa)* + (a(bb)* +  b(aa)* ab(bb)* ) (ba(aa)* ab(bb)* )* ba(aa)* ) b )*

that is same as (we can discard `Λ`  here) RE:

> ( (a(bb)* +  (aa)* ab(bb)* ) (ba(aa)* ab(bb)* )* a  +  ( b(aa)* + (a(bb)* +  b(aa)* ab(bb)* ) (ba(aa)* ab(bb)* )* ba(aa)* ) b )*

This is the RE you where looking for.

I am not sure that it can be further simplified. I am leaving it as an exercise for you.

In linked question I suggested a non-formal and analytical method but it was hard to apply and find RE for this DFA and this question demonstrate power of Arden's theorem and step by step solution.

**Edit**:

My previous regular expression is correct but hard to grapes because unsymmetrical form. Below I am writing new form of RE that is more symmetrical.

We have equation-(5), (6) as follows:

> `5.`   Q<sub>3</sub> =  Q<sub>0</sub>b(aa)* + Q<sub>1</sub>ba(aa)*
>     `6.`   Q<sub>1</sub> =  Q<sub>0</sub>a(bb)* + Q<sub>3</sub>ab(bb)*

Both are symmetrical in construction and easy to learn. (*read my comment after eq-(5) above*)

To evaluate value of state Q<sub>1</sub> in terms of Q<sub>0</sub>, I putted value of Q<sub>3</sub> from equation-(5) into equation-(6) that gives me equation-(7)  as follows:

> `7.`   Q<sub>1</sub> =  Q<sub>0</sub>(a(bb)* +  b(aa)* ab(bb)* ) (ba(aa)* ab(bb)* )*

Similarly, to evaluate value of state Q<sub>3</sub> in terms of Q<sub>0</sub>, we can put value of Q<sub>1</sub> from equation-(6) into equation-(5) that will give us new form of equation-(8) as follows:

> Q<sub>3</sub> =  Q<sub>0</sub>b(aa)* + Q<sub>1</sub>ba(aa)*
>     Q<sub>3</sub> =  Q<sub>0</sub>b(aa)* + (Q<sub>0</sub>a(bb)* + Q<sub>3</sub>ab(bb)* ) ba(aa)*
>     Q<sub>3</sub> =  Q<sub>0</sub>b(aa)* + Q<sub>0</sub>a(bb)* ba(aa)* + Q<sub>3</sub>ab(bb)* ba(aa)*

Now, we can have equation-(8) in our desired form:

> `8.`   Q<sub>3</sub> =  Q<sub>0</sub>(b(aa)* + a(bb)* ba(aa)* )(ab(bb)* ba(aa)* )*

Now, we have equation-(1), (7), (8):

> `1.`   Q<sub>0</sub> = `Λ` + Q<sub>1</sub>a  + Q<sub>3</sub>b
>     `7.`   Q<sub>1</sub> =  Q<sub>0</sub>(a(bb)* +  b(aa)* ab(bb)* ) (ba(aa)* ab(bb)* )*
>     `8.`   Q<sub>3</sub> =  Q<sub>0</sub>(b(aa)* + a(bb)* ba(aa)* ) (ab(bb)* ba(aa)* )*

Now, we can have equation-(8) in our desired form:

> `8.`   Q<sub>3</sub> =  Q<sub>0</sub>(b(aa)* + a(bb)* ba(aa)* )(ab(bb)* ba(aa)* )*

Now, we have equation-(1), (7), (8):

> `1.`   Q<sub>0</sub> = `Λ` + Q<sub>1</sub>a  + Q<sub>3</sub>b
>     `7.`   Q<sub>1</sub> =  Q<sub>0</sub>(a(bb)* +  b(aa)* ab(bb)* ) (ba(aa)* ab(bb)* )*
>     `8.`   Q<sub>3</sub> =  Q<sub>0</sub>(b(aa)* + a(bb)* ba(aa)* ) (ab(bb)* ba(aa)* )*

Now put value of state Q<sub>1</sub> and Q<sub>3</sub> into equation-(1):

> Q<sub>0</sub> = `Λ` + Q<sub>0</sub>(a(bb)* +  b(aa)* ab(bb)* ) (ba(aa)* ab(bb)* )* a  + Q<sub>0</sub>(b(aa)* + a(bb)* ba(aa)* ) (ab(bb)* ba(aa)* )* b

can also be written as:

> Q<sub>0</sub> = `Λ` + Q<sub>0</sub> ( (a(bb)* +  b(aa)* ab(bb)* ) (ba(aa)* ab(bb)* )* a  + (b(aa)* + a(bb)* ba(aa)* ) (ab(bb)* ba(aa)* )* b )

Next, apply Arden's theorem on this equation, and we get the final RE:

### Regular Expression for even numbers of *'a'* and even numbers of *'b'*:

> ( (a(bb)* +  b(aa)* ab(bb)* ) (ba(aa)* ab(bb)* )* a  + (b(aa)* +
>   a(bb)* ba(aa)* ) (ab(bb)* ba(aa)* )* b )*

Can one step further simplified as below:

```
((a + b(aa)*ab)(bb)*(ba(aa)*ab(bb)*)*a + (b + a(bb)*ba)(aa)*(ab(bb)*ba(aa)*)*b)*
```

Comment: For an implementation of the algorithm used, see my answer to a related question found at https://github.com/whekman/red-dragon-book/blob/master/ch3/3_7.md

Answer (score 1):

Let E is the language with even number of a's and even number of b's, and below is the Regular expression for language E.

[00 + 11 + (01+10)(11+00)*(01+10)]*

00 = type1

11 = type2

(01+10)(00+11)*(01+10) = type3

Suppose that we are scanning along a word in the language of E from left
to right reading the letters two at a time. First we come to a double 0 (type1),
then to a double 1 (type2) , then to another double 0 (type 1 again). Then perhaps we come upon a pair of letters that are not the same. Say, for instance, that the next two letters are 10. This must begin a substring of type3. It starts with an undoubled pair (either 01 or 10), then it has a section of doubled letters (many repetitions of either 00 or 11), and then it finally ends with another undoubled pair (either 01 or 10 again). One property of this section of the word is that it has an even number of 0's and an even number of 1's. If the section started with a 10, it could end with an 01 still giving two 0's and two 1's on the ends with only doubled letters in between. If it started
with a 10 and ended with an 01, again, it would give an even number of
0's and an even number of 1's. After this section of type3 we could proceed
with more sections of type, or type2 until we encountered another undoubled
pair, starting another type3 section. We know that another undoubled pair will
be coming up to balance off the initial one. The total effect is that every word
of the language of E contains an even number of 0's and an even number
of 1's

Answer (score -1):

this is DFA of even-even language
containing  even number of 0 and 1

its RE would be this

```
(00 + 11 + (01+10)(01+10) (00 + 11)*)*
```

here, it will accept lemda that is even nmber of 0 and 1

or will accept (00) even nmbr of 0 and there is no 1 means here nmber of 1 is even.or either (11) in that case nmber of (0) are even .. so you can check it will generate strings containining even nmber of 0 and 1 ..

hope it will sort out your problem