# Shortest regex for binary number with even number of 0s or odd number of 1s

Tags: regex, regular-language, finite-automata

Write an expression that contains an even number of 0s or an odd number of 1s

I got it down to:

```
1*(01*01*)* + 0*10*(10*10*)*
```

where the first part represents an even number of 0s and the second part an odd number of 1s

However, there's supposed to be a simplified solution that I'm not seeing. Any tips?

Comment: What programming language uses `+` for alternatives in regexp? AFAIK, that's only used in automata theory, not when programming.

Comment: Why not `substr_count()`?

Comment: Whoops, may have tagged the wrong thing. Sorry

Comment: homework huh? LOL

Comment: I tried this on regexpal.com and it seemed to work: `^(1(11)*|(00)+)$`

Comment: **Any tips?:** -- Learn from this answer [How to write regular expression for a DFA using Arden theorem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17420332/need-regular-expression-for-finite-automata/17434694#17434694) Note final state for you is `Q3`.

Comment: Btw your RE is not correct you are missing many strings

Comment: @Barmar In Automata theory `+` as binary operator is Union, and if it appears in supperscript form as unary operator that means repetition for one or more times.

Comment: Maybe detect the failure case? (odd number of 0s AND even number of 1s)

Comment: I just wrote a regex from scratch OP and came up with a regex of exactly the same length as yours (and 95% identical). I intentionally didnt read over yours first so I suspect there might not be a shorter expression.

Comment: I concur with @OGHaza the base state conditions don't allow for fewer states

Comment: Check my updated answer. `0*1(0|10*1)*` is an even shorter regex for the odd-1s part

Comment: @user3085290 Do you want "an even number of 0s _and_ an odd number of 1s" or "an even number of 0s _or_ an odd number of 1s"?

Answer (score 19):

Odd-1s part: `0*1(0|10*1)*`

Even-0s part, depends:

1. Empty string is correct: `(1|01*0)*`
2. No-0s is even-0s: `(1|01*0)+`
3. Must have at least two 0s: `1*(01*01*)+` (as in OP)

**old answer:** correct under case 1 and 2

```
(1*(01*0)*)+ | 0*1(0*(10*1)*)*
```

---

Kudos to @OGHaza for helpful comments.

Comment: [example](http://regexr.com?37nfn) of string with odd number of 1s that isn't matched

Comment: @OGHaza you're right, had a `+` instead of a `*` there, thanks! http://regexr.com?37nfq

Comment: It doesn't appear to match the empty string (zero `0`s is still even). Easy to fix though: changing any or both `+`s to `*`.

Comment: @DPenner yeah, I'm intentionally forcing it to be non-empty

Comment: Well you shaved 4 chars from OPs regex and I think you've taken it as far as it can go ;) +1

Comment: That's what one might think..until someone else comes along :-)

Comment: Your answer is not correct as it is also possible to generate incorrect string from your RE `(1*(01*0)*)+` use to write `111010` that is incorrect. You may like to check this answer: [Need Regular Expression for Finite Automata: Even number of 1s and Even number of 0s](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17420332/need-regular-expression-for-finite-automata-even-number-of-1s-and-even-number-o/17434694#17434694)

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan it is correct because it has two zeros. It is even 0s OR odd 1s

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan aren't the 2nd and 3rd parts redundant? Plus, they don't force an odd number of 1s. They force at least one, but there could be any number.

Comment: Yes correct is `(1*01*01*)* + (0*10*10*)*10* + 0*1(0*10*10*)*`  by mistake I added `*` at 1

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan those force at least one 0 (inside parentheses). Again, 2nd and 3rd part are redundant, right? (let's delete old comments so this doesn't grow too long)

Comment: Yes I checked again and now I think last-two are repentant. We can remove any one.

Answer (score 11):

Making use of the fact that even-length strings ALWAYS satisfy your constraints:

```
^(([01]{2})*|1*(01*01*)*)$
```

Comment: This uses as many symbols as my regex, but I think that very nice catch about even length strings deserves this bounty. Note that this regex requires the no 0s-is-even-0s case.

Comment: It would be shorter if `1*(01*01*)*` was replaced by `(1|01*0)*` (as in @JuliánUrbano's solution). But yes, very smart, +1!

Comment: and even more importantly...shortest execution time as well!

Answer (score 1):

Define "shortest". If you're looking for the shortest evaluation time (i.e. fastest) then make sure you do not use capture groups.

[here's an example in javascript](http://jsfiddle.net/gillyspy/PJGg2/)

```
^(?:1*(?:01*0)*)+|0*1(?:0*(?:10*1)*)*$
```

which shows as 20% faster than this expression that uses capture groups but will give you the same answer

```
^(1*(01*0)*)+|0*1(0*(10*1)*)*$
```

Comment: I mean shortest as in fewest symbols. After all, non-capturing groups are just language-dependent sugar.

Comment: yes I think we know what you were going for @JuliánUrbano.  So my question is for the op.  You're not also the op are you?  But for you julian...curious on in what practical scenarios would you (you specifically not the general "you") would prefer the shortest length of expression and not the shortest evaluation time?

Comment: the bounty is just for fun, to see if there is something shorter

Comment: your comment came in before I saved my question so to clarify: so no practical purpose, just for fun? Also, can we get confirmation that you and  the op mean "shorter" in the same way?   And who is down-voting me any way, is there some way in which my answer / comments are not relevant given the information we are provided?

Answer (score 0):

The most simplified solution I found is:

```
1+0(0+1)((1+0)(1+0))*
```

Answer (score 0):

With the fewest symbols,

```
1*(01*01*)*
```

Answer (score 0):

what about this expression:

`(1(11)*+(00)*)`