# RE: Number of a's is divisible by 6 and Number of b's is divisible by 8

Tags: regex, dfa

> Find a regular expression which represents strings made of {`a,` `b`}, where number of `a`'s is divisible by 6 and number of `b`'s is divisible by `8`.

I tried to create a DFA which accepts such strings. My idea was to use all the remainders mod 6 and mod 8 leading to a total of 48 remainders. Thus each state in DFA is a pair `(r, s)` where `r` varies from 0 to 6 and `s` varies from 0 to 7. Start state (as well as accepting state) is `(0, 0)` and by we can easily give transitions to states by noting that if we input `"a"` the state `(r, s)` transitions to `(r + 1, s)` and on input `"b"` it transitions to state `(r, s + 1)`.

However it is too difficult to work with a DFA of 48 states and I am not sure if this can be minimized by using the DFA minimization algorithm by hand.

I am really not sure how then we can get to a regular expression representing such strings.

Comment: No this can't minimized and its regular expression would be very long and complex, even if you try to find regex for 'b' /2 and 'a' / 2 will be very complex [Read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17420332/need-regular-expression-for-finite-automata-even-number-of-1s-and-even-number-o/17434694#17434694)

Comment: From the final regular expression I have written you should understood that you need to write all possible combination for 6a and 8b -- Yes you can write comparatively simple "Regex"  (not regular expression in formal languages).

Comment: Your proposed DFA is already minimal.

Comment: Thanks to all for the comments! I was actually trying to teach this DFA / regex topic to someone and found that they got this question in exam. I think the question should have been limited to the description of DFA rather than finding an actual regex.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh yes, writing actual regex/dfa for this language is not a question should be asked in Exma. – it is strange if it was asked....

Comment: If you need more appropriate answer read this [Minimum number of states in DFA for the given language?](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/21802/minimum-number-of-states-in-dfa-for-the-given-language/21866#21866)

Comment: perhaps it was asked by mistake in exam

Answer (score 1):

If you are allowed to use lookaheads:

```
^(?=b*((ab*){6})+$)a*((ba*){8})+$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/mthQiw2JQZ0q3XVJ)

Example of matched string: `bbaabbaabbaabb`

Idea is simple: We know how to match string having number of `a`s divisible by 6 - `^((b*ab*){6})+$`, also we know how to match string having number of `b`s divisible by 8 - `^((a*ba*){8})+$`. So we just put one regex to lookahead, and another one to matching part.

In case if you **also** need to match strings consisting only of `a`s or only of `b`s, then the following regex will do:

```
^(?=b*((ab*){6})*$)a*((ba*){8})*$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Examples of matched strings: `aaaaaa`, `bbbbbbbb`, `bbaabbaabbaabb`

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/CLwgNlEv3gu2Q_Qf)

Comment: Can you share any word matching your expression and condition. Unfortunately I am not able to match to required word.

Comment: @Murthy I added link to demo. Basically any string consisting of `a` and `b`, where number of `a`s is divisible by 6 and number of `b`s is divisible by 8 will match.

Comment: @ Ulugbek Umirov I tried the word "babbabbaabbaab" which is tried at online [regex evaluator](http://regexr.com/38npa) Please share any working word for my understanding of expression.

Comment: @Murthy OP stated `made of {a, b}`, it means only `a` and `b` symbols are allowed.

Comment: good, thought it seems OP is not looking for Regex (but actually RE in formal languages)